# Running Powershell Script after Build automatically

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, powershell-2.0, tfsbuild

My question is that how can I trigger a powershell script when I check-in a code in VS2013 automatically.
see what I have done till now is that as soon as I check in a build is triggered. Separately I have a PS script that I run after the build succeeds, now what i want is that the script should run automatically as soon as the build succeeds, and i do not have to do anything to trigger the sript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XAML build in tfs, you can specify the path to a custom script in **Build Definition--2.Build--5.Advanced--Post-build** script path, which will run after the MSBuild activity successfully completes.

[image]

If you are using the windows build agent, then you can simply add a PowerShell build step after the build step. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/index#env_vars

Comment: i know this...what is now need is the command to write in this to open a ps1 file and execute it

Comment: Add and check in the ps1 file into TFS, and select the ps1 file by clicking the ellipsis.